# How to use if / else statement with a JSON fetch API response Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, if-statement, fetch-api

I have two working code snippets that I would like to link with `if`/`else` logic. The first part of the code receives a JSON response from a web API. `JSON.TEMPERATURE` is the key variable needed.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const api_url = 'https://www.placeholder_URL.com/api/getTemperature'

fetch(api_url)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((myJSON) => {
    console.log(myJSON.TEMPERATURE); // **This returns a number between 8 and 15**
  });
```

The second part of the code plays a MIDI note. In the case below, `note` # 60 which is the Middle C. C# would be `note` 61, D `note` 62 and so forth.

```
let easymidi = require("easymidi")
let output = new easymidi.Output("mindiPort", true)

let sendNote = (noteValue, duration) => {
    output.send("noteon", noteValue)

    setTimeout(()=> {
        output.send("noteoff", noteValue)
    }, duration);
}

setInterval(() => {
    let noteValue = {
        note: 60,   // **need to change this number depending on JSON.TEMPERATURE**
        velocity: 100,
        channel: 1
    }
    sendNote(noteValue, 500)
}, 2000);
```

What I am looking to achieve is an `if`/`else` where the note played is dependent on `JSON.TEMPERATURE`.

Something like:

`if JSON.TEMPERATURE ==` 8, play `note` 60

`if JSON.TEMPERATURE ==` 9, play `note` 61

`else`, play note 55

I would also like to run the API request every 5 seconds.

Comment: embarrasingly yes - I tried to solve this problem with python and I couldnt. I am still trying to learn Javascript

Comment: your current code will continually send the note every 2 seconds (for a duration of half a second each time) - do you want to do that or just send it once?

Comment: @Jamiec just once please. And thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the setInterval iniside of the .then of the fetch request, that way the note will be sent after the api request has finished and you have received the JSON response.

How you've currently implemented it it will call sendNote every 2 seconds. Additionally you want to do the api call every 5 seconds. This means that we want to clear the sendNote interval of the previous api call that's why the interval variable is there and we call clearInterval if interval is set.

Of course you can abstract it by putting some of this code into functions to make it look prettier but this is the gist of it

```
let interval;
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const api_url = 'https://www.placeholder_URL.com/api/getTemperature'
setInterval(() =>
fetch(api_url)
   .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
   })
.then((myJSON) => {
   if (interval) {
     clearInterval(interval);
   }
   interval = setInterval(() => {
      let note;
      if (myJSON.TEMPERATURE == 8) {
        note = 60;
      } else if (myJSON.TEMPERATURE == 9) {
        note = 61;
      } else {
        note = 55;
      }
      let noteValue = {
         note: note,
         velocity: 100,
         channel: 1
       }
       sendNote(noteValue, 500)
   }, 2000);
 }), 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like all you need is an `if` statement such as

```
if(myJSON.TEMPERATURE == 8){
   note = 60;
}
else if(myJSON.TEMPERATURE == 9){
   note = 61;
}
else{
  note = 55;
}
```

So just put this in place of your `console.log` part.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const api_url = 'https://www.placeholder_URL.com/api/getTemperature'

fetch(api_url)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((myJSON) => {
    let note;
    if(myJSON.TEMPERATURE == 8){
       note = 60;
    }
    else if(myJSON.TEMPERATURE == 9){
       note = 61;
    }
    else{
      note = 55;
    }

    let noteValue = {
        note: note,   
        velocity: 100,
        channel: 1
    }
    sendNote(noteValue, 500)
  });

let sendNote = (noteValue, duration) => {
    output.send("noteon", noteValue)

    setTimeout(()=> {
        output.send("noteoff", noteValue)
    }, duration);
}
```

Comment: you are an angel. What took you 50 seconds has already taken me >5 hours between python and Javascript. Let me test the code. Thanks Alot.

Comment: looks like I need a catch block for the fetch api. That is throwing an error. However, this is great help (especially with JS syntax) - I should be able to take it from here :) :)

Comment: tweaked it a bit based - also based on the answer below and it now works. Thanks!